# Prove of the Parseval's theorem for Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

If $x[k]$ and $X[r] $ are the pair of discrete time Fourier sequences, where $x[k]$ is the discrete time sequence and $X[r]$ is its corresponding DFT. Prove that the energy of the aperiodic sequence $x[k]$ of length $N$ can be expressed in terms of its $N$-point DFT 
as follows:

$$E_x=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|x[k]|^2=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{r}^{N-1}|X[r]|^2.$$

Could anyone one help me with this prove? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the DFT is an unitary transformation.

Comment: In the middle expression, replace _one_ of the $x[k]$ by the weighted sum of $X[r]$'s as specified in the _inverse_ DFT formula.  Then, interchange order of summation.  For details of this idea for Fourier transforms (where integrals instead of sums are involved), see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/342425/15941).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The proof is straightforward.  Assume that $X$ and $x$ are related as follows:

$$X[r] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]\, e^{i 2 \pi k r /N}$$

Then

$$|X[r]|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]\, \sum_{k'=0}^{N-1} x^*[k']\, e^{i 2 \pi (k-k') r /N}$$

and

$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=0}^{N-1}|X[r]|^2 &= \sum_{r=0}^{N-1} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]\, \sum_{k'=0}^{N-1} x^*[k']\, e^{i 2 \pi (k-k') r /N} \\ &=  \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]\, \sum_{k'=0}^{N-1} x^*[k']\, \sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{i 2 \pi (k-k') r /N} \end{align}$$

The inner sum is a geometric series and has the value

$$\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{i 2 \pi (k-k') r /N} = \frac{e^{i 2 \pi (k-k')}-1}{e^{i 2 \pi (k-k')/N}-1}$$

Note that the RHS is zero unless $k=k'$; in that case, you should be able to see that the sum is simply $N$.  We then write

$$\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{i 2 \pi (k-k') r /N} = N \delta_{kk'}$$

where $\delta_{kk'}$ is $0$ when $k \ne k'$ and $1$ when $k=k'$.  Therefore

$$\sum_{r=0}^{N-1}|X[r]|^2 = N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} |x[k]|^2$$

and Parseval's theorem follows.

Comment: why $$|X[r]|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]\, \sum_{k'=0}^{N-1} x^*[k']\, e^{i 2 \pi (k-k') r /(N-1)}$$, but not $$|X[r]|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]\, \sum_{k'=0}^{N-1} x^*[k']\, e^{i 2 \pi (k+k') r /(N-1)}$$? Thanks.

Comment: Because of the complex conjugation.

Comment: Thank you Ron. You help me a lot.

Comment: Isn't the relationship $X[r]=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1}x[k]e^{-i2\pi kr/N}$?

Comment: @Alejandro: it doesn't matter.

Comment: Because $X^*(k)=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}x(m)e^{j2\pi km/N}$, right?

Comment: @Alejandro: you would need to conjugate $x[m]$ as well.  Look, work it out for yourself in the way I have outlined.  Whether or not there is a minus sign in the exponential is a matter of convention.  If your textbook says there is one, then follow my analysis and put the negative sign in.  The result will be the same.