# How does one define the Fourier transform of a probability distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Say $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are two probability distributions on a $m$ element set.

Then I see an equality written as,

$$\sqrt{m} \vert \vert p_X - p_Y \vert \vert _2 = \sqrt{ \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \vert  \hat{p_X} (k) - \hat{p_Y} (k)\vert ^2  } $$

- Can someone help derive and understand this? 
  I don't know what is the defintion and meaning of these $\hat{p}$ quantities on the right.

  What is the meaning of this identity?

Comment: It is likely that $\hat{p}_X$ is the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function), rather than a result of Fourier transform. Then $\hat{p}_X(k)$ is just the probability that $X = k$.

Comment: Can you complete the derivation with that interpretation?

Comment: This seems to be a *definition* of a distance between probability distributions (close to, but different from [Hellinger distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance#Discrete_distributions)), not an equality.

Comment: This identity is simply Parseval's theorem in the case of the discrete Fourier transform. For a proof of this, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346894/prove-of-the-parsevals-theorem-for-discrete-fourier-transform-dft

Comment: @Budenn Sorry but your interpretation is highly unlikely.

Comment: @Did Then the answer by Chester below is probably the correct one. Should I delete the comments?

Comment: @Budenn Of course Chester's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your title question, you are dealing with a function whose domain is: $\{0, 1, \ldots, m-1\}$. The probability distribution can be represented by a vector, $p_X \in \mathbb{R}^m$ with the usual 2 norm.

Since this is discrete, finite function, its Fourier transform is then found using the discrete Fourier transform. This is defined as

$$
\hat{p}_X(k) = \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} p_X(j)\exp(-2\pi ikj/m) , \;\; k=0, 1, \ldots, m-1
$$

As I mentioned in the comments, the identity you ask about is called Parseval's theorem. This energy preservation identity (up to a scale factor) is true for the discrete Fourier transform and the continuous transform - or any unitary transformation. To be clear, the identity you've written states:

$$\sqrt{m}||p_X-p_Y||_2 = ||\hat{p}_X - \hat{p}_Y||_2$$