# Understanding the Theorem in Sec . 7.8. of Titchmarsh's Book

Tags: proof-explanation, riemann-zeta, holder-inequality, mellin-transform

The following is a part of the theorem in Section 7.8. in Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*:

[image]

My questions:

1- I need to study Parseval's formula but lets say that the formula $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert F(it)\rvert^2\,dt = \int_0^\infty \lvert f(x)\rvert^2\,\frac{dx}{x}$ given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702318/a-parseval-like-theorem-for-mellin-transforms) is correct. Thus $I(\sigma)$ in the picture above must be $\int_0^\infty \lvert \phi(ix e^{-i \delta})\rvert^2\,\frac{dx}{x}$ and not $\int_0^\infty \lvert \phi(ix e^{-i \delta})\rvert^2\,\frac{dx}{x^{1-2 \sigma}}$, so why the later one is derived instead?

2- Holders's inequality $\int_a^b fg~ \mathrm{d}x  \leqslant \left\{\int_a^b f^p ~\mathrm{d}x\right\}^{\frac{1}{p}} \left\{\int_a^b g^q ~\mathrm{d}x\right
\}^{\frac{1}{q}}$ does not imply the inequality given in the picture above for $I(\sigma)$, so how the given inequality in the picture holds?

Comment: [Don't use images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)